# Installing Qt on an AWS instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, qt

I would like to install the Qt development library on an AWS instance.

Running

```
> yum search qt | grep devel
```

on an AWS t2.micro instance produces no matches.

Does one have to install Qt from source? For a well-established library such as Qt this doesn't make sense. Can you confirm, either way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced the same situation some time ago. I ended up building Qt [manually](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.9/build-sources.html). If you really want to install the GUI-version of Qt without actually having any GUI (due to headless AWS instance) there are actually 2 more options: [qt-downloader](https://github.com/engnr/qt-downloader) or [install-qt-action](https://github.com/jurplel/install-qt-action)

But in most cases the first approach is prefered:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

I hope this info would be useful =)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems that you have to build it yourself as according to Amazon they don't support graphical libraries on the micro (free) instance.  Here is the company line from [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=460141).

*The Amazon Linux AMI was designed to be a completely headless server for use in cloud computing, so it does not support an X Windows System in the traditional sense. We have not provided user interface libraries such as GTK+ and Qt....*

If you wanted to install it yourself, here is a helpful post from Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662529/building-qt-libraries-on-ubuntu-linux

Comment: Just a note, you can use QtCore and QtNetwork to make cli-only servers for example.